# Angular 2 - ViewEncapsulation.Native is undefined in ES5

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want to use ViewEncapsulation.Native in Angular 2 code written in pure JS i.e.m ES5. But it gives undefined. How to access it in es5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
var AppComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: '<div>Test</div>',
      viewEncapsulation: ng.core.ViewEncapsulation.Native
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function () {
        (...)
      }
    });
```

Comment: `ng.core.ViewEncapsulation.Native` doesn't seem to work although it not undefined. Angular 2 is still emulating instead of using native shadow DOM

Comment: It should be `encapsulation` instead of `viewEncapsulation`.

Comment: Use `ViewEncapsulation.None` instead of `ViewEncapsulation.Native`